# CakePHP- include PHPUnit in php.ini

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit

I am trying to get PHPUnit working on my cakePHP application. 
I have downloaded and setup all the necessary files

In my php.ini file , I put

`include_path = ".;c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\pear\PHPUnit"`

But I do not think this is correct.

When running cakePHP's `app/test.php`, I get 2 warnings to include `PHPUnit\Autoload.php`

Comment: That worked for me in 2.x: [PHPUnit](http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/07/21/cakephp-and-phpunit/).

Comment: @mark The problem was that It was pointing to PHPUnit rather than PEAR. And then CakePHP prepends the path of the local app with the include_path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so for whatever reason, no one here decided to hep me out on this one.. Which is a little bit frustrating.. But no matter! I'm going to provide the solution for others whom like me, are new to PHP and PHPUnit, and want to get into unit testing

Steps I followed :

1. Install PEAR, download from the [PEAR website](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.php)
2. If you find yourself having trouble, follow this [guy's tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UH90nGNXab0)
3. [Download PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de/)
4. Put PHPUnit in local file.. (www or equivalent)
5. Install PHPUnit with PEAR (If integration with cake, make sure you follow [these steps](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html))
6. If you already installe v.4, you can downgrade using  the command

> `pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit`  
>   
>   and install PHPUnit-3.7.32

Finally  visit php.ini and make sure that path included points to the `pear` directory
In my case `include_path = ".;c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/pear"`

Cheers and happy coding